I found a list of 25 words on my old desk in my mothers house. Is there any way to know how to recover this?
I just found a list of 25 english words (not my native language) on a white paper in my mother's house. This has to be old, because i don't touch that desk for a long time, 10+ years.
I have been searching for some info, regarding the 25 seed phrases but i dont have any conclusive anwser.
I found the BIP0039 dictionary, but the problem is that half of my words are not on this list.
Words like, flute, salute, point, are not on the BIP0039.
I dont know what coin it belongs neither what wallet i used back then. I rembember waiting 1 day to syncronize the blockchain to my computer, but i already tried the Bitcoin core wallet, but it doenst have any seed phrase recovery option.
Are there any other dictionaries i can compare my list with, so i can guess what coin this wallet refers too ? What steps would you take to find out ?
Thank you all.

Perhaps the words that are not on the list are decoys? Have you tried just using the words that are on the list?

The Electrum wallet was published in 2011 and originally used it's own recovery-phrase AKA seed-phrase system before BIP-39 was written. Their system did not use a fixed word list.
I suspect a 25 word phrase is likely to be a 24-word seed-phrase plus one passphrase.
From what I have read, Electrum seed phrases had 12 words not 24. Maybe there was a choice in the 2011 version?
I would try Electrum anyway.


https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=electrum+seed



Thank you for your anwser. I just tried the Electrum wallet, and it matches more words than the BIP39 one, but not all. Like 2 or 3 are still not found.
But thank you, i fell a bit closer :)

It could be old blockchain wallet recovery phrase. Old Blockchain.info legacy wallets can use from 15 to 25 words. Some of them are not a part of the BIP39. They had their own very big list. They started using BIP39 standard in 2016. It's not that obvious to recover that wallet.
Do you have any other information on that white paper?

No, only a 25 word list :(

that's enough. I've dealt with few similar cases before feel free to hit me up
